# How to apply constraint satisfaction problem to vertical/horizontal automated layouts? like swing and flex layouts

Tags: layout

I need to build a vertical and horizontal automated layout system. There is very little documentation on the internet about how to implement it, but I hardly found something that might help me "Constraint satisfaction problem". But I don't really know how to apply it to what I'm doing...

Somebody has some information about this rare topic?